# C90 and typedef

Tags: c, struct, typedef, c89

I had `struct point {(...)};` defined. But with C90 it seems I have to do it with typedef. How do I do this correctly? `typedef struct point {} point;`? `typedef struct {} point;`? `typedef struct point {};`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
typedef struct Point { ... } MyPoint;
```

and then use both kinds of declarations:

```
struct Point p1;
MyPoint p2;
```

Comment: `struct` names and `typedef` names are in separate namespaces, so you can get away with `typedef struct T {...} T;`. This is also why your attempts to use `point p;` after declaring `struct point {...};` failed: you have to declare variables of type `struct point` using the `struct` keyword: `struct point p = {0, 0};`.

Answer (score 3):

Both of these are correct:

```
typedef struct point { /* ... */ } point;
typedef struct { /* ... */ } point;
```

The first version defines `struct point` and then defines `point` as an alias for it, while the second defines `point` as an alias for an anonymous struct.